# PHP string append is overwriting instead when loading in content from files within a loop?

Tags: php, string-concatenation, file-read

I am attempting to read in multiple files, where the filename of each file is contained within a central file "order.txt", and take the content and append it to a single string variable in PHP.

This is my current approach:

```php
$order = file("order.txt");
$content = "";
foreach($order as $line) {
    $content = $content . file_get_contents($line);
}
return $content;
```

**order.txt**

```
one.txt
two.txt
three.txt
```

However, when "content" is returned, it only contains the data within the last file (in this case, "three.txt"). How can I ensure the content from all files are appended to the "content" variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried your code, but PHP's `file` returns lines *with line breaks* (`\n`). So instead of reading `one.txt`, you are trying to read from a file `one.txt\n`.

The reason why you actually get the contents of `three.txt`, is that the last line presumably has no newline character in the end ([actually it's not called a line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729692/845034)). Always add newlines; if the file is written automatically, make sure to add `\n` after each line.

You can add `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` as second parameter to [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).

Btw: Your PHP doesn't seem to be configured correctly as you don't see any warnings about that `one.txt\n` doesn't exist. You should turn on all error messages, set `display_errors` to `true` or at least monitor PHP's error log.